Tmux force options
So I am having some problems
I wish to set my panel transparent after the theme is loaded but theme always overrides the option to set the bar transparent even after setting it on the last line.
I'll leave the config if it helps.
set -g default-terminal "tmux-256color"
set -ag terminal-overrides ",xterm-256color:RGB"

set -g prefix C-a
unbind C-b
bind-key C-a send-prefix

unbind %
bind | split-window -h 

unbind '"'
bind - split-window -v

unbind r
bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf

bind j resize-pane -D 5
bind k resize-pane -U 5
bind l resize-pane -R 5
bind h resize-pane -L 5

bind -r m resize-pane -Z

set -g mouse on

set-window-option -g mode-keys vi
set-option -g status-position top
set -g base-index 1
setw -g pane-base-index 1

bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'v' send -X begin-selection
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'y' send -X copy-selection

unbind -T copy-mode-vi MouseDragEnd1Pane

set -sg escape-time 10

# tpm plugin
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tpm'

# other plugins
set -g @plugin "janoamaral/tokyo-night-tmux"
set -g @tokyo-night-tmux_window_id_style digital
set -g @tokyo-night-tmux_pane_id_style dsquare
set -g @tokyo-night-tmux_show_datetime 0

set -g status-style bg=default

run '~/.tmux/plugins/tpm/tpm'

